# how to ensure my flutter application is compatible with android 4.1?

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to make possible to install and use my flutter application on a phone which has a android OS version 4.1, but when i run my code on a simulator the result is :
[image]

i cannot open the app no matter how many times i try it.

and my api and sdk versions are : `minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 29`
is my api version the problem? play store says about this the minimum OS compatible is 4.1 but it does not work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Install and run your app in Android Studio and see what the verbose output and error message are.

Comment: Also Flutter itself supports Android SDK 16 and on, but not all plugins will. One of your external plugins might be specifying a minimum version that is incompatible with Jelly Bean.

Comment: I really recommend upping your minimum sdk to 21. Below 5.0 will not be supported by most plugins.

Comment: the error is `Waiting for observatory port to be available...java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get
provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider`

Comment: @Stijn2210 i put the minimum sdk to 21 like you said but the app does not install because the sdk version is to advanced towards the phone android version on which the app is trying to install